# Generic collection of restricted types

Tags: c#, generics, collections, covariance

I have a class who requires the following definition :

```
public class Table<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : IRowDef, new()
```

I want to create a collection of it and map types with the instances.  So I try :

```
public sealed class TableCollection : IEnumerable<Table<IRowDef>>
{
   private Dictionary<Type, Table<IRowDef>> _tableDictionary;

   public Table<IRowDef> GetTable<T>() where T : IRowDef, new()
   {
        Table<IRowDef> table = null;

        if (_tableDictionary.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            table = _tableDictionary[typeof(T)];
        }
        else
        {
            table = new Table<IRowDef>();
            _tableDictionary.Add(typeof(T), table);
        }

        return table;
   }

   ...
}
```

But I can't make it work.  The following lines and several others gives the same error  :

```
private Dictionary<Type, Table<IRowDef>> _tableDictionary;
```

The error, translated, tells IRowDef must be non abstract and have a parameterless constructor.  I know it comes from the "new()" type restriction on the Table class definition, but it is required by the code inside this class.  I known I could solve this by using a specific class type who would contains a parameter less constructor, for example :

```
private Dictionary<Type, Table<ClientTable>> _tableDictionary;
```

But different types of table must be supported and is the reason why all of them implements IRowDef.

Does anybody knows how I can solve this?

Comment: Why don't you use a `Dictionary<Type, object>` and cast when required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need a collection of tables, but a `Table<X>` is not compatible with a `Table<Y>` and a `WhateverCollection<Table<X>>` is not compatible with a `WhateverCollection<Table<Y>>`, even if `X` is an interface type and `Y` implements this interface.

Why it that? Asssume that you have

```
List<IAnimal> animals = new List<Elefant>();
animals.Add(giraffe); // Ooops!
```

> Put that in your pipe and smoke it!
>
> ```
> // DOES NOT WORK!  
> T<Base> b = new T<Derived>(); // T<Derived> is not assignment compatible to T<Base>!!!
> ```

but

```
Base b = new Derived(); // OK
```

---

The trick is to have two table classes: One non-generic base class and a derived generic class:

```
public abstract class Table
{}

public class Table<T> : Table
     where T : IRowDef, new()
{
     private readonly ObservableCollection<T> _rows = new ...;
}
```

Now you can declare a

```
private Dictionary<Type, Table> _tableDictionary;
```

Or if you want to stick to deriving from the an observable collection, declare a (non-generic!) `ITable` interface instead of a `Table` base class and let `Table<T>` implement `ITable` then declare the dictionary as `Dictionary<Type, ITable>`.

Comment: I declared an empty ITable interface and my Table<T> class declare an implementation of it.  My TableCollection class implements IEnumerable<ITable> and my _tableDictionary is declared as Dictionary<Type, ITable> and it works great.  Thanks.

Comment: You can also add all common members of tables that do not depend on the generic type `T` to `ITable`. For instance, all tables could have an `int ID` column and a `Save()` method. This makes the interface a bit more useful. Btw.: an interface not having any members, is called *marker interface*.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the `new()` constraint and use `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` to create new objects. This moves the check from compile time to runtime. The C# compiler translates `new T()` to a `Activator.CreateInstance` call anyway.

Comment: What if OP couldn't modify the `Table` class?

Comment: @nopeflow did he say that? I missed that. Then he needs to either use a concrete class type or he needs to write something like `Dictionary<Type, Table<T>>` where `T` is properly constrained to be `IRowDef, new()`. The only way to say that a type has a `new()` is to use generics.

Comment: no, he didn't but I curious what could be done in that situation. What is more, using `Dictionary<Type, Table<T>>` is not solution IMHo, because the OP want's to store a map of different types as dictionary values.

Comment: @nopeflow that's a good point. Then he is out of luck because he can't have it all. He has to relax some constraint. Restrict the types in the dictionary, drop new(), or store something like `object` or another base class and cast at runtime.; I kind of dislike these convoluted generics questions. If you have to ask the design is already to complicated. I think he should drop the new constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Olivier Jacof-Descombes proposed one of possible approaches. The other one (applicable only if you can modify `Table` class):

```
public interface ITable
{
    //Some needed methods, f,e,
    IRowDef GetSth();
}
```

then:

```
public class Table<T> : ..., ITable where T : IRowDef, new()
{
    IRowDef ITable.GetSth()
    { 
         return (IRowDef)this.GetSthImplInsideTable(); // cast is optional
    }

    public T GetSthImplInsideTable() { /* impl */ }
}
```

You could use it as:

```
private Dictionary<T, ITable> _tablesDict;
```